# Is $f(x)=x+\sin x$ bounded variation

Tags: calculus

Does $f(x)=x+\sin x$ has a bounded variation on $\Bbb R$? I dont know the concept of bounded variation.

Comment: HINT: The total path on the $y$ axis is the total variation. Since $sin(x)$ repeats every $2\pi$, then you should just take the variation $V(x) = 2 + ${2\pi} etc.

Comment: Check the total variation of your function.

Answer (score 6):

An unbounded function $f(x)$ (as yours is on $\Bbb R$) cannot be of bounded variation. Try to apply the definitions of bounded variation and unbounded to see this.

Answer (score 0):

In his book 'I want to be a Mathematician' Halmos recalls how Doob (I think) 
succinctly explained what  bounded variation means: A function is of bounded
variation if it has "length". All those absolute values in the definition indicates that we 
are trying to approximate funtion with polygons. If we can approximate as closely as we want 
with polygons, the function is of bounded variation. Usually, bounded variation definition is only 
for closed intervals in $\mathbf {R} $.